# How to get clicked button value in console.log

Tags: ionic3, angular6

I have three buttons and I want value of that button whom i will clicked. I have done some code. please help me as I am novice in Ionic.

File name: Donate.html

```
<ion-grid>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col col-6 >
    <button ion-button #ref (click)="addDetails(ref.value)" name="masjid" id="1" value="masjid" full block>
      Masjid
    </button>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col col-6 >
    <button ion-button #ref (click)="addDetails(ref.value)" name="school" id="2" value="school" full block>
      School
    </button>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col col-12 >
    <button ion-button name="fitrana" id="3" value="fitrana" #ref (click)="addDetails(ref.value)" full block>
      Fitrana
    </button>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

File name: Donate.ts

```
addDetails(value) {
console.log("value:",value);
}
```

Now when I clicked on any button it showed me value undefined. Please help me thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do below changes.

First of all you need to change your click function. It should be like below one -

```
<ion-grid>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col col-6 >
    <button ion-button #ref (click)="addDetails($event)" name="masjid" id="1" value="masjid" full block>
      Masjid
    </button>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col col-6 >
    <button ion-button #ref (click)="addDetails($event)" name="school" id="2" value="school" full block>
      School
    </button>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col col-12 >
    <button ion-button name="fitrana" id="3" value="fitrana" #ref (click)="addDetails($event)" full block>
      Fitrana
    </button>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

**Pass $event in click function which is nothing but reference of clicked element.**

Then your function should be like below one.

```
addDetails(value) {
console.log("value:",value.currentTarget.name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way I would suggest is to add a function on click as you did and pass the value which represents the button to the function like

```
<button (click)="addDetails('button1')>...</button>
<button (click)="addDetails('button2')>...</button>
<button (click)="addDetails('button3')>...</button>
```

Then you could get those values in the function to print it in console